# C# How Do I Take An Animated GIF In base64 String Format To MemoryStream And Then To PictureBox?

Tags: c#, base64, animated-gif

I'm writing an app in which an animated GIF is contained in base64 string format, then loaded into a byte array, then put into a memory stream and finally into a picture box. Here's the code I have so far:

```
if (GameInfo.TitlePageImagePresent == true)
{
    byte[] TitlePageImageBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(GameInfo.TitlePageImage);
    MemoryStream memTitlePageImageStream = new MemoryStream(TitlePageImageBuffer, 0, TitlePageImageBuffer.Length);
    memTitlePageImageStream.Write(TitlePageImageBuffer, 0, TitlePageImageBuffer.Length);
    memTitlePageImageStream.Position = 0; 
    pbGameImages.Image = Image.FromStream(memTitlePageImageStream, true);
    memTitlePageImageStream.Close();
    memTitlePageImageStream = null;
    TitlePageImageBuffer = null;
}
```

The problem is that only one frame of the animated GIF makes it through to the picture box. Is there an intermediate process I need by which all the individual images of an animated GIF should be handled in order to get the full animation?

Comment: Is this about WinForms? I don't think that particular control supports animation in GIFs.

Comment: This is a Windows Forms Application created in Visual Studio 2013. The control I'm trying to load the animated GIF into is a picture box, which does support animated GIFs. The problem I'm having with the above code is that only one frame of an animated GIF makes it through to the picture box, rather than the entire animation.

Comment: Is GameInfo.TitlePageImage the GIF? Can you post code showing how you are loading that value?

Comment: You are not allowed to close the stream as long as the image is in use.  The image data is read lazily.  Just delete the Close() call and don't bother worrying about closing it at all.

Comment: Justin Loveless: First I convert the animated GIF into a base64 string. Then I write it to a binary file using BinaryWriter. Then I open it using BinaryReader. Then I assign it to a string variable, where it should be a base64 string again. Then I load it into a byte array. Then I put it into a MemoryStream. And finally, it goes into a picture box control. This works just fine for all the image formats I'm using except animated GIFs. Apparently, the above code does not handle animated GIFs, it just grabs one frame and puts it in the picture box. I want the whole animation, not just one frame.

Comment: Hans, I tried your suggestion. It didn't fix the problem, but it's not interfering with other image types being loaded successfully either. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you considered that the issue is the initial conversion from GIF to the base64 string?

Comment: Please provide a _complete_ code example, including the base64 data you are importing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve